# $C_1\le C_2x^{-2\alpha}+C_3x^{2\beta+1}\le C_4$...can one deduce $c\le x\le C$?

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have the inequality

$$C_1\le C_2x^{-2\alpha}+C_3x^{2\beta+1}\le C_4$$

where $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4>0$ are positive constants which depend on $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $x>0$.

Can one deduce an inequality of the form

$c\le x\le C$,

for $c,C>0$ positive constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

As everything is positive, $ C_3x^{2\beta+1}\le C_4$ implies
 $$x\le (C_4/C3)^{1/(2\beta+1)}$$
and $C_2x^{-2\alpha}\le C_4$  implies
$$ x\ge (C_2/C_4)^{1/2\alpha}.$$